# HttpListener Authentication at specific AbsolutePath

Tags: c#, authentication, webserver, httplistener

I've searched stackoverflow for an exaple on how I can enable Basic Authentication in the HttpListener for a specific AbsolutePath.

For exaple;

```
public static byte[] SendResponse(HttpListenerRequest request)
{
    string AbsolutePath = request.Url.AbsolutePath.Replace("/", "");

    if (AbsolutePath == "GetAppointments")
    {
        //Enable basic authentication
    }
    else if (AbsolutePath == "GetStatus")
    {
        //Don't use authentication
    }
}
```

Is there way a posabillity to achieve this? or do I have to create 2 HttpListeners on different ports. I know that webservers are also able to generate different authentications based on htaccess so it should be possibe right?

Thanks in advance,

Sincerely,

Joey Erdogan